# How to send formatted html email using swiftmailer?

Tags: 8, emails, page-controller

How can I send styled html body using custom module to send an email. I am using swiftmailer module. With that I am able to send normal body, but I am not able to use html tags or css. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swiftmailer only sends mails, it doesn't let you create HTML / plaintext content for emails.

I think that you want to use a module like [mimemail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) to do this.

I came across this article that describes how to style mails send out using mimemail.

[Theming HTML Mail sent through Mime Mail](https://www.drupal.org/node/958146)

This guide is made for Drupal 7, but the module has been made for Drupal 8 as well, so I think you might just create a `mimemail-message.html.twig`